# Prepend to command line arguments in linux/bash

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-arguments

I want to pass along the command line arguments given to script to another command, but I also want to add some additional arguments on the front first. How can I do this with bash?

This will send all the arguments through to the command:

```
command $@
```

But I want something more like:

```
command [argument1, argument2, $@]
```

How can you do something like this in bash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have `grep foo` and you want to add `-f` before `foo`, you can use `grep -f foo`. The same thing applies here:

```
cmd argument1 argument2 "$@"
```

Comment: @bt, note the use of quotes here. It's very important: it passes the  arguments exactly as received.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly! In what cases can not putting quotes around $@ mess you up?

Comment: `$@` behaves just like `$*` and is subject to word splitting and globbing. The most common manifestation is that you can't do anything with filenames containing spaces.

Comment: eh, looking for a way to do it like this instead `cmd "x y $@"` so that I can manipulate "$1" in `cmd` later

Comment: @AlexanderMills This is a really bad design decision that I strongly urge you to reconsider. The script will be fragile and unable to handle parameters with spaces. If you insist though, you can do this with `cmd "x y $*"`

Comment: yeah understood, maybe you can answer this question that I just asked - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402700/append-argument-to-arguments-list/402704

Answer (score 19):

@ThatOtherGuy's answer is correct.

If you were looking to "unshift" a couple of arguments into the positional parameters, do this:

```
set -- arg1 arg2 "$@"
cmd "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more generic way to do this (recommended), use this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function xyz {
  echo "${args[@]}"  # arguments will printed out
}

function abc {
    local args=()
    args+=(argument1)
    args+=(argument2)
    args+=("$@")
    xyz "${args[@]}"
}
```

to test, source the above code

```
source script.sh && abc
```